# How to load Wordpress functions wp_head() into Laravel <head> tag?

Tags: wordpress, laravel

We have developed website using hybrid technology i.e Laravel and Wordpress

Could anyone explain, is it possible include WP functions into Laravel blade.template?
Because in laravel header blade template need to add or include the wp_head() wordpress function.
Need to add the all tags will be in one place (According to the W3C Standards rules)

same like the below code. please have a look.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="title" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="type" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.website.com/" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="{{url('/')}}/images/top-bg.jpg" />
        <title>Website Title</title>

        // wordpress funtion 
        <?php wp_head(); ?>

    </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just have to include the file which contains the wp_head() functions somewhere in your code (preferable on the backend side) then you should be able to use it in blade too.

Answer (score 0):

To load all `Wordpress` functions in any `PHP` application is by include file `wp-load.php`. In Laravel app include it in your `bootstrap/autoload.php`. Any way, `wordpress` function always has side effect when invoked. Unexpected `echo`, etc. This will also load functions in all enabled worpress plugins too. Give your best attention about it. I mean security of your application.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress function there is one file called as **wp-load.php**
only include this file in any **PHP** application with the Relative path.

See the below example :-

```
require(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . '/wptheme/wp-load.php'); 
wp_head();
```

This will also load functions in all enabled worpress plugins files.